# Only the last file is shown when typing os.path.splitext()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to rename files and delete the last 4 characters (_RRR) in each of the files. All the files are shown when I run `os.listdir`. when splitting into tupple, only the last file gets displayed.

```
file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext()
print(revit_name)
```

After typing `file_name`, only the last filename is shown and not the rest.
Please help
Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing this in a loop, you're overwriting `file_name` each time through the loop. If you want to get all of them, append them to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You seem a bit unclear in your question.

If you a splitting an extension, you pass the file name as a parameter:

```
old_name = 'mydata.RRR'
file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(old_name)
os.rename(old_name, file_name)
```

Alternately, you can use any method to make the new string.

---

You may be thinking of this?

```
names = [name for name in os.listdir() if name.endswith('R15')]
for name in names:
   os.rename(name, name[:-3])
```

or, for the terse:

```
[os.rename(name, name[:-3]) for name in os.listdir() if name.endswith('R15')]
```

Hope this helps!  Keep coding! 
 Keep notes.

Comment: Okay. So I'll just give an example ... I have a folder with more than 2000 files in them all ending with the R15. I want to remove R15 from all these files and keep the remaining name as is. So I have got the path and all the files are shown. After Using .split, the files are getting renamed in the notebook. But in the actual folder.. just the last file is getting renamed.

Comment: Edited. Better?  If still not working, you need to provide more code.